# Cómo hacer un JOIN entre dos tablas sin relación mediante tabla intermedia

Tags: sql

Tengo 4 tablas que quiero relacionar para extraer usuarios que cumplan con ciertas características:

- `Usuarios u`
- `Pedidos p`
- `LineaDePedidos l`
- `Productos pr`

Las relaciones entre tablas son las siguientes:

```
u.Id = p.UsuariosId
p.Id = l.PedidosId
```

Hay una relación 1 a N entre `Productos pr` y `LineadePedidos l`:

```
pr.ProductCode = l.ProductCode
```

Lo que me falta es hacer un `JOIN` y meter aquí la tabla `Productos` para extraer la información del producto del pedido que se encuentra en la tabla `Productos`.

No sé cómo hacer un `JOIN` dentro de otro `JOIN`.

Estoy intentando hacer algo como esto:

```
SELECT u.XXX, u.XXX, l.XXX, p.XXX, pr.XXX FROM Pedidos p JOIN Usuarios u ON p.UsuariosId = u.Id JOIN LineaDePedidos l ON p.Id = l.PedidosId JOIN Productos pr (JOIN LineaDePedidos ON pr.ProductCode = l.ProductCode) GROUP BY u.XXX, u.XXX, l.XXX, p.XXX, pr.XXX
```

Comment: Esta es la query que estoy intentando hacer, pero no se como postearla en la pregunta
SELECT
u.XXX, u.XXX, l.XXX, p.XXX, pr.XXX
FROM Pedidos p
JOIN Usuarios u ON p.UsuariosId = u.Id
JOIN LineaDePedidos l ON p.Id = l.PedidosId
JOIN Productos pr (JOIN LineaDePedidos ON pr.ProductCode = l.ProductCode)
GROUP BY u.XXX, u.XXX, l.XXX, p.XXX, pr.XXX

Comment: Puedes usar [edit]

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a la comunidad. Te invito a hacer el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y leer [¿cómo preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea bien recibida por parte de la comunidad. Además, para poder reproducir tu problema y encontrar una solución fácilmente nos sería de gran ayuda un [ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Dicho esto, deberías compartir la consulta SQL que quieres hacer [editando tu pregunta (pulsando en este enlace)](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/382558/edit).

Comment: @OscarGarcia, el resto de tablas no tienen dos campos relacionables entre sí. Para llegar a LíneaDePedido debes pasar por Pedidos, ya que esta tabla si tiene un campo para relacionar al usuario. Productos es la tabla genérica que contiene todos los artículos que hay en la web así como su descripción y características. Esta se podría relacionar con LíneaDePedido porque cada línea de pedido contiene el código de producto.

Comment: Por favor @Altu, ¿podrías revisar mi respuesta y dejar un comentario en ella si no funciona o no soluciona tu problema?

Comment: Acabo de ver que haces uso de `GROUP BY` en campos como `l.XXX` y `pr.XXX`. ¿Por qué motivo agrupas por esos campos? ¿Es realmente necesario? Lo digo porque es probable que no estés viendo todos los datos relacionados por culpa de estar siendo consolidados por esos agrupamientos.

Comment: ¿Pudiste comprobar si alguna respuesta soluciona tu problema? Si no es así deja un comentario explicando en qué falla o qué le falta para poder ser una respuesta correcta.

Answer (score 0):

Ya tienes relacionada la tabla `LineaDePedidos l` en tu consulta SQL, así que donde pones:

```
JOIN Productos pr (JOIN LineaDePedidos ON pr.ProductCode = l.ProductCode)
```

Debería poner:

```
JOIN Productos pr ON pr.ProductCode = l.ProductCode
```

Tu consulta SQL quedaría:

```
SELECT u.XXX, u.XXX, l.XXX, p.XXX, pr.XXX
FROM Pedidos p
LEFT JOIN Usuarios u
  ON p.UsuariosId = u.Id
LEFT JOIN LineaDePedidos l
  ON p.Id = l.PedidosId
LEFT JOIN Productos pr
  ON pr.ProductCode = l.ProductCode
GROUP BY u.XXX, u.XXX, l.XXX, p.XXX, pr.XXX
```

Answer (score 0):

Acá te dejo un ejemplo....

`tabla1` (tiene su `id`) -> tabla_intermedia (esta hereda de ambas con los siguientes campos: `id_tabla1` e `id_tabla2`)

<- `tabla2` (tiene su `id`)

```
SELECT * 
    FROM tabla1 AS T1
        JOIN tabla_intermedia as TIN ON T1.id=TIN.id_tabla1
        JOIN tabla2 AS T2 ON T2.id=TIN.id_tabla2
```

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a la comunidad. Te invito a hacer el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y leer [¿cómo escribo una buena respuesta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) para que tu respuesta sea bien recibida por parte de la comunidad. Como podrás ver, el OP ha usado varios `JOIN` en su consulta SQL, por lo que parece que no necesita la teoría. Necesita corregir el error que ha cometido en su consulta SQL.